# How to fetch these error/mismatch strings based on time intervals

Tags: regex, string, unix, sed, awk

I have a log file like this. I don't want to fetch the accounts that were previously fetched at like 09:28

```
Connected to feeder version 2.1 09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 01234567EUR
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 0123456755JPY
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 0123426567INR
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 012345698887USD
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 012343422567EUR
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Account 0234456783388KRY not set up
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Account 0234454467888CNH not set up
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Error : Closing Balance of Account 02344567888GBP Doesn't match
Connected to feeder version 2.1 09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 01234567EUR
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 012343356755GBP
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 012342654467INR
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 01234564498887USD
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 01234663422567EUR
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Account 02344567833886KRY not set up
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Account 023445446788866CNH not set up
10:28:30 29/03/2014 Error : Closing Balance of Account 02344567888GBP Doesn't match
```

Now i used the following sed command to fetch the error accounts

```
sed -n "
s/.* Closing Balance of Account \(.*\) Doesn't match/\1/p;
s/.* Account \(.*\) not set up/\1/p
 "
```

But How to extract only the new accounts. For eg i don't want accounts extratced at 9.28 again to come at 10.28 list. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: How do you know that the 09:28 lines were "previously fetched"? Is there some marker in the log file?

Comment: Hi, basically I'm writing a monitoring script which checks this log file for say every 10 mins and if there is any error then it'll send those error account list. So after 1hr if I receive few more accounts with error/mismatch I would need only the new accounts in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store most recent timestamp in a separate file and pass it back to sed:

```
s='09:28'
sed -n "/^$ts/"'!{s/.* Closing Balance of Account \(.*\) Doesn.t match/\1/p; s/.* Account \(.*\) not set up/\1/p;}' file
02344567833886KRY
023445446788866CNH
02344567888GBP
```

**EDIT:** To store latest timestamp in a file use:

```
tail -1 file | egrep -o '^[0-9]+:[0-9]+' > tmp.txt
```

And use this value:

```
s=$(<tmp.txt)
sed -n "/^$ts/"'!{s/.* Closing Balance of Account \(.*\) Doesn.t match/\1/p; s/.* Account \(.*\) not set up/\1/p;}' ff
```

Comment: But is it possible to store the time-stamp automatically every-time.?

Comment: Yes very much possible. You can do `tail -1 file|egrep -o '[0-9]+:[0-9]+'` and store its output in some file.

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks a lot I have a slight doubt here. I used the command suggested by you to get the latest time stamp and I got it also. tail -1 hopes.txt|egrep -o '[0-9]+:[0-9]+' > tmp.txt
but when I use this tmp.txt in this sed command sed -n "/^$ttmp.txt/"'!{s/.* Closing Balance of Account \(.*\) Doesn.t match/\1/p; s/.* Account \(.*\) not set up/\1/p;}' hopes.txt it's giving me everything actually not the latest

Comment: Hi anubhava can you help me with my question here.

Comment: The link is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091512/how-to-use-while-loop-only-to-read-filenames-of-a-specific-pattern-unix?noredirect=1#comment39042798_25091512

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the lines after the last "Connected to feeder" line: Read the file backwards; print each line until you come to the indicated pattern; re-reverse the lines; search for the account ids:

```
tac logfile | 
awk '/^Connected to feeder/ {exit} 1' | 
tac | 
grep -oP '(Closing Balance of )?Account \K\w+(?= not set up| Doesn)'
```