# How to use while loop only to read filenames of a specific pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

Suppose I have the following files in a particular directory.

```
ABC_TEXT_FILE_365.csv
ABC_TEXT_FILE_365_07h32.csv
BCD_TEXT_FILE_432.csv
BCD_TEXT_FILE_432_08h28.csv
FGB_TEXT_FILE_567.csv
FGB_TEXT_FILE_567_09h45.csv
```

Now I want to read only the files which has *h**.csv pattern in them and then perform more operations.

But I know `while read filename`
will read all the filenames rite.? Is there any workaround for this. Please help

Comment: you could put in a if statement with a regex to meet your specific needs

Comment: you mean to say `[ if -f *h*.csv ] then; ***while through the loop*** done fi` will do that.?

Comment: @Tom Fenchh has what I was thinking

Comment: @user2647888: Is Tom's answer working for you?

Comment: @user2647888 I have updated my answer so it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean all files that match `*h*.csv`, in which case you might want to use a `for` loop like this:

```
for i in *h*.csv; do 
    while read line; do 
        # do some stuff, e.g. echo "$line"
    done < "$i"
done
```

In case it is a possibility that you have any directories that match the pattern, you might want to also add a test to ensure that each item in the loop is a file. That would be:

```
for i in *h*.csv; do 
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then 
        while read line; do 
            echo "$line" 
        done < "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @Nachiket I'm sorry, there was an error in that code. I have corrected it now, so hopefully it should work. Let me know if you have any further problems.

Comment: @Nachiket my mistake, I incorrectly assumed that you were the OP. Anyway, the code should work now.

Answer (score 1):

A potential problem with a `for` loop (that is, `for f in *h*.csv; do ...` or `for f in 'find ...'`) is that if there are too many files available, then this will make the command-line too long.  That's because the `*` or internal `find` is expanded into a *big* command-line before the `for` loop is processed.

An alternative and robust pattern is:

```
find . -name \*h\*.csv | while read f; do echo process $f; done
```

That is, `find` finds all of the files with that pattern and prints them out, `while` reads stdin one line at a time, into `f`, and processes it.

Comment: I like this approach.  Additionally the OP might want to look at using xargs on the right side of the pipe following the find

Answer (score 0):

simple answer would be,

```
dir=$1 <or hardcoded path>
for filename in `find $dir -name "*h*.csv"`
do

echo $filename
#job you want to do further

done
```